# How to write a number range in c for a condition

Tags: c, range

I just started programming in C and in general. I am having trouble with the syntax. I know what I want to say logic wise but I just don't know the correct formatting/syntax.

Thank you!

How do I write:
"while integer n is not equal to 10 or 20"

How do I write:
"while integer n is between 10 and 20 inclusive"

How do I write:
"while integer n is between 10 and 20 inclusive or 30 and 40 inclusive"

How do I write:
"while integer n is not between 10 and 20 inclusive or 30 and 40 inclusive"

Comment: Let's see what you have so far in terms of code.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: If it is homework, how are you asking anything but us to do it for you?

Comment: Question: Can you write this simpler one?: "*while integer n is not equal to 10*". Unless you can, asking the rest is pointless. If you can, maybe somebody here will show you how to extend it.

Comment: And the smack down begins. You can/should probably consult some very basic references before asking here. You should provide some code with questions showing what you have tried.

Comment: this is not homework. im not even enrolled in a class right now

Comment: @penguinshin There is a sense in which the [homework] tag does not care if the question was given to you for homework by someone who is going to issue a grade on you performance: it means that the question's value is primarily pedagogical. This one could go either way as far as I care, but if you are *trying to learn c* then you might have served yourself better by reading up on the syntax and deducing the answer for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while( n != 10 && n != 20 )
while( n >= 10 && n <= 20 )
while( ( n >= 10 && n <= 20 ) || ( n >= 30 && n <= 40 ))
while( ! ( n >= 10 && n <= 20 ) && ! ( n >= 30 && n <= 40 ))
```

Comment: Was what fair?  This is a perfectly legitimate question.  It is certainly true that there is a plethora of sources to look for this information, but I fail to see why so many people are upset by questions about syntax.

Comment: Yes, it was a perfectly legitimate question for a *homework assignment* that everyone is obviously suspecting this to be.

Comment: I'm not enrolled yet in any CS class...I'm just trying to learn how to program through harvards publicly free cs50 course online...and this wasn't a question on that btw, i just had an idea to solve one of the problems and i needed to know how to write that idea out...